# Cannot add to mySQL database using XAMPP for mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

I hello I am currently trying to add data to my user login database however for some reason my database it not being updated when I register a new user.

here is my code from user.inc.php:

```
<?php
//checks if username already exists in database
function user_exists($user)
{
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($user);
    $total = mysqli_query("SELECT user_id FROM user_system WHERE user_name= ('$user')");

    return (mysql_result($total, 0) == '1') ? true : false;
}

//checks if username and password combo is valid
function valid_credent($user, $pass)
{
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($user);
    $pass = sha1($pass);
    $total = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT user_id FROM users 
                        WHERE user_name = '$user' AND 
                        user_password = '$pass' ");

    return(mysql_result($total, 0) == '1') ? true : false;
}

//add user to database
function add_user($user, $pass)
{
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($user));
    $pass = sha1($pass);

    $queryStr = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password) VALUES ('$user', '$pass')";
    $R = mysqli_query($mysqli,$queryStr);
}
?>
```

I also have warning on my register page when I try to add view errors

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PostalCloud/core/user.inc.php on line 8
```

line 8:

```
return (mysql_result($total, 0) == '1') ? true : false;
```

I have tried using "sanitize()" however that doesn't exists.

UPDATE: Still getting errors after modifying code. Here part of my register.php code and I have a init.inc.php that uses mysqli to connect to database.

```
<?php
include('init.inc.php');

$errors = array();

if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['repeatPassword']))
{
    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'The username cannot by empty. ';
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['repeatPassword']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'The password cannot by empty. ';
    }

    if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['repeatPassword'])
    {
        $errors[] = 'Password verification failed. ';
    }

    if(user_exists($_POST['username']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'The username you entered is already taken. ';
    }

    if(empty($errors))
    {
        add_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        $_SESSION['username'] = htmlentities($_POST['username']);

        header('Location: protected.php');
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

init.inc.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$exceptions = array('register', 'login');

$page = substr(end(explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])), 0, -4);

if(in_array($page, $exceptions) === false)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) === false)
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    }
}

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'user_system');

$path = dirname(__FILE__);

include("{$path}/core/user.inc.php");
?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. These are deprecated and don't support new features of MySQL.

Comment: Indeed.   You seem to be switching back and forth a bit there, which is very odd.   Also switching to mysqli prepared statements will prevent having to escape every variable.  I suggest starting this script over with safer and more efficient connections

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **mysql_query()** is returning a boolean instead of a result resource. There are two reasons this can happen:

1. You performed query that returns success/fail instead of a result
   set (e.g. UPDATE)
2. Your query failed

your query contains single quotes on column names..this should be removed :

```
$total = mysqli_query("SELECT user_id FROM user_system WHERE user_name= '$user'");
```

Comment: I did that and ended up with more errors: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PostalCloud/core/user.inc.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PostalCloud/core/user.inc.php on line 8

Comment: mysqli queries need to reference the database connection as well.  check this:   http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp